# Set print margins in Textmate?

Tags: macos, printing, textmate, margins

I'm using OS X 10.8.5 with TextMate 2.0-beta.6. I want to print a text document, but it appears there are no margins (or the margins are too small for my taste):

[image: Textmate default margins]

I visited Textmate's ***Page Setup***, but it does not appear to provide settings related to the margins:

[image: Textmate page setup]

How do I set the print margins to 0.5-inch or 1-inch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference [18 Printing](http://manual.macromates.com/en/printing.html) would suggest it can't be done...

> **To the amusement of some and the frustration of others, TextMate
>   currently features only limited printing capabilities.**
>
> That means you can only use the document font with no syntax
>   highlighting and no options except the standard printing options plus
>   header and footer fields as shown below.

However, **it can be done when printing to PDF.**

[TextMate Tricks: An Automation to Produce PDFs](https://pragprog.com/magazines/2009-10/textmate-tricks)

> **I made it possible to configure things like margins and fonts for the
>   PDF with a YAML file.** It doesn’t exist yet and the code will run fine
>   without it, but let’s add one more shortcut for that. This time, we
>   don’t need any code and we can just build a snippet. A snippet is a
>   chunk of boilerplate code we can customize to our needs.
>
> Click on that plus in the lower left of the Bundle Editor one more
>   time and choose New Snippet this time. Give it a name like Configure
>   PDF Builder and replace the examples with this code:

```
# Set margins below. These are in PDF points (72 per inch).
top_margin: ${1:72}
left_margin: ${2:72}
right_margin: ${3:72}
bottom_margin: ${4:72}
# Set font, size, and line spacing below.
font: ${5:Courier}
font_size: ${6:10}
spacing: ${7:15}
```

Read the complete article for full instructions.

Comment: Amazing a commercial editor can't print properly... And its not limited to TextMate - TextWrangler appears to suffer the same fate. I really amazed.....